# Sampling a musical instrument (or re-tuning MIDI)

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

I'd like to try to convert a piece of MIDI music made with SoundNote to another tuning (not microtonal or even split-black-keys, just a slightly different tuning for each note). I searched for pitch parameters and it seems it only accepts "C" or "Db", not frequencies, and plays the piece in 12-tone equal temperament. (Am I right? Or could I somehow make a MIDI note sounding at a different frequency than those pre-defined notes?)

So I'm trying to recreate piano sound with Play function. I add some harmonics to a sine wave but the more I add, the worse it sounds. Adding attack and decay shouldn't be very hard but for adding the harmonics in right amounts, I'd need to sample. I could have access to a piano and get some sound samples. In what file format should I record them so that Mathematica could run a Fourier transform on it? What functions should I use? How do I give a sound file as an input?

Or, is there any way to re-tune a MIDI file with some other program after I compose it with Mathematica and export?

Comment: I believe you need to include a MIDI Pitch Bend Event of the correct value for each channel that you wish to "tune."  I don't think this is possible from *Mathematica* without manually writing binary data to a file.  See e.g. http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php for a starting reference.

Answer (score 3):

Several audio file formats are supported by the `Import` and `Export` functions in *Mathematica*. These formats and the exact details of how to use them with `Import` and `Export` are [provided in the Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AudioFormats.html).

Between `Import` and [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fourier.html), I think you should be able to get what you want. Here's a couple of evaluations like what you might end up using:

```
data = Import["http://www.nch.com.au/acm/8kgsm.wav", "Data"];
dft = Fourier[data];
```

Re the second part of your question: I don't know about re-tuning MIDI with other programs. There may be a sound/audio-related Stack Exchange website where you'd be more likely to find people who could help you with that.

Comment: I have the following code: data = Import["sample.wav", "Data"];
dft = Fourier[data] And it doesn't work though sample.wav is in the same file as the notebook.

Comment: Oh, I just found my mistake. It requires a full file name.